# Xamarin Ios Localization

Tags: ios, xamarin, localization

I tried multiple times to translate my Storyboard on Xamarin but can't make it work ... First i have a Splashcreen that well call my MainStoryboard (So inside AppDelegate)

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions) {
        var lang = NSLocale.PreferredLanguages[0];

        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
        UIViewController initialViewController = Storyboard.InstantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController;

        Window.RootViewController = initialViewController;
        Window.AccessibilityLanguage = lang;
        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
```

I'have a storyoboard named Main.storyboard. Got en.lproj and fr.lproj inside ressource folder. Inside each folder i have a specific file named Main.strings like in the documentation (Following my project folder)

[image]

Example of Maiin.strings in French :

```
"458.text" = "Rechercher";
"473.text" = "Parametres";
"501.text" = "Informations";
"480.normalTitle" = "Mise a jour";
"481.normalTitle" = "A propos";
```

plist file which is also correct:

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
  <string>fr</string>
</array>
```

For me all of this is correct but it doesn't work ... I still have "???" that i'have put in the storyboard. (in 458 item there is "???" but with the localization it should be converted in "Rechercher").

Thank you for your help !

Comment: have you read https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/localization_and_internationalization/#storyboard

Comment: i also had the same problem fixed by duplicating the Main.String files. if you still feel any problem feel free to comment

Comment: Yes this is what i mean by "like in the documentation" ...

Comment: Duplicate the main.string with Main~iphone.strings and  Main~ipad.strings in both English and french folder.

Comment: But i Guess i don't use class size. I Will try and let you know

Comment: It worked ! Duplicating files works very well ... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as the project tree structure, you do not have to use the `Resource` directory, here I am using `./Design/Base.lproj/` for my LaunchScreen/Main stroyboards, and `Support/en.lproj` and `Support/fr.lproj/` for my non-developmental languages:

The **key factor** with the `.strings` files, other than their containing folder name, is that they are flagged as **`BundleResources`** build types.

```
.
├── AppDelegate.cs
├── Assets.xcassets
│   ├── AppIcon.appiconset
│   │   └── Contents.json
│   ├── Contents.json
│   └── LaunchImage.launchimage
│       └── Contents.json
├── Design
│   └── Base.lproj
│       ├── LaunchScreen.storyboard
│       └── Main.storyboard
├── Entitlements.plist
├── Info.plist
├── Main.cs
├── Media
│   └── hayley.jpg
├── Support
│   ├── en.lproj
│   │   ├── LaunchScreen.strings
│   │   └── Main.strings
│   └── fr.lproj
│       ├── LaunchScreen.storyboard
│       ├── LaunchScreen.strings
│       └── Main.strings
├── ViewController.cs
├── ViewController.designer.cs
└── iOSLocalization.csproj
```

The entries in the `info.plist` such as `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` do NOT effect the language shown, nor does removing entries from the `CFBundleLocalizations` array (this entry is for the App Store).

Yours **should** have two entries, `en` and `fr`, otherwise remove the `.lproj` folder for the languages you are not including in your app. (You can also set all the files in that folder to a build type of `None`.

**Make sure that your device or simulator is set to correct language that you are testing your localizations against.**

Comment: Thank you for the expanation about CFBundle. I deleted en.lproj because it is my development language. But trying what youu said to solve didn't worked. I must let fr.lproj inside Resource folder otherwise it doesn't works